# iMac mid-2011 GPU upgrade

Tags: mac, imac

I'm looking for which GPU would be appropriate to replace my mid-2011 iMac's original GPU which is a Radeon HD 6750M, I'm looking for a $ 100 budget card, but one that may be newer to support a forced macOS upgrade. I would appreciate if someone could recommend me some GPUs within the budget but above all compatible.

Comment: As I posted on your now-deleted Q in Hardware recs, this is a hugely complex subject - see https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2011-imac-graphics-card-upgrade.1596614/ See also https://macexpertguide.com/2011-imac-graphics-card-upgrade-how-to/

Comment: Thank, the second link is useful, it contains a list of GPU and that is what I'am looking for

Comment: The first link also shows several lists of GPUs with pros & cons. It is considerably more comprehensive than the quick work-through of the second.

Comment: SteelWalter: Here is a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440495/high-sierra-partition-lost-after-deleting-windows-partition) posted by a user who has Big Sur installed on a 21.5-inch, Mid 2011 iMac. You might want to follow this question and/or post any questions about installing as comments.